# Angular 6 firebase get list from cloud firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

i want to know how to get lists from cloud firestore.

I upload list like this :

```
export interface Data {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  address2: string;
  pscode: string;
  ccode: string;
  name2: string;
}

constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore){
    this.notesCollection = this.afs.collection(`imones`, (ref) => ref.orderBy('time', 'desc').limit(5));
}

  notesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Data>;

//creating item in list (imones)

createItem(){
  this.notesCollection.add(this.busines);
}
```

**Now the question is how to get all list items from there ?**

That's my try :

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore){
  this.items = this.notesCollection.valueChanges();
}
  items: Observable<Data[]>;
```

HTML :

```
 <p *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}}</p>
```

ERROR:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Again error :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over an observable.
the `*ngFor` loop allows you to iterate only on iterables (arrays, sets)

You have 2 options:

1. Use the built-in [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in order to iterate over an observable.
   e.g:

   `<p *ngFor="let item of items | async">{{item.name}}</p>`
2. Subscribe to the observable and update a variable with the latest result from it (the observable result in your case is an array):

   ```
   this.notesCollection.valueChanges()
                       .subscribe((items) => this.items = items);
   ```

Comment: You are still setting `this.items` to an observable, remove the first assignment. the assignment should be inside the subscription, not outside.

Comment: example please ?

Comment: this.notesCollection.valueChanges().subscribe((items) => this.items = items);  , still got the same error on this.items

Comment: Property isScalar is missing

Comment: Show your `items` variable decleration

Comment: you can see it in the picture.

Comment: items: Observable<Data[]>

Comment: It's not an obserable anymore. it should be items: Data[] or any[]

Comment: 0 erros, with 2 subscribe method. But shows nothing at all in html.

Comment: Then you have nothing in your collection.

Comment: I have 5 items in my collection